# How can I open my .py file in the python terminal (noob asking)?

Tags: python, terminal

I've been trying to open a graphical user interface through the command line in Python 3.7. I was just wondering how I would do this? How do I access the file it's located in? Do I copy and paste the file (C:\Users...) and run python ui.py through it?

Thank-you.

Comment: `cd` to the directory containing `ui.py`. So `cd C:\users\...\folder`. Then you can run `python ui.py`

Comment: I thought so, but that just throws up syntax errors.

Comment: Then you most likely have an error in your actual Python file. You may want to try searching the syntax error or opening a question with the code posted and stating what the syntax error is

Comment: It just says invalid syntax  with a caret under C:\.

Comment: you generally would run python files from a system terminal rather than a python terminal (cmd on windows, terminal on mac, etc for linux). You could import a .py file, and it will be executed, but some things may act differently (the common `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom won't be executed)

Comment: Ah that is my bad. I didn't see `python terminal`. @Aaron is right. You can also wrap everything in a function, call it something like `main`. Make sure your python terminal is executed from the directory in which `ui.py` is. So `C:\users\folder` and executed `python`. Then you can do `from ui import main` and this will allow you to call the `main()` or anything else from that file

Comment: My issue with cmd is that I am operating from a PC which does not have admin rights, so cannot execute python as it's not in the PATH (adding it to such would require admin rights), hence why I am using the python terminal instead (it was working like this through my colleague's workspace).

Comment: @BloodyRubbishIron just for future reference, editing your user `PATH` environment variable rather than the system `PATH` should not require admin, and works just as well. You can also just type in the full path of your "python.exe", but that gets a bit tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command line rather than the python terminal

`cd` into the directory of the project and then run `python ui.py`.

Copying the file to another directory may break the program as it could rely on other files in its project directory.

If you really want to stay in the python terminal you could

```
> import os

> os.chdir(PATH_TO_FILE)
```

then run the file as normal

hope this helps

Comment: The issue I seem to have is that if I do that it says invalid syntax underneath the C:\ part of the directory. This as working on my colleague's PC last time I spoke, but he is on holiday now, so don't want to bother him.

Comment: Yeah, though I have tried it without and it doesn't work regardless.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to view python file from command line, open command line and use cd

for me I have my python scripts in a folder on my Dekstop so I would put:

```
C:\Users\YourName>cd Desktop

C:\Users\YourName\Desktop>cd Python

C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\Python>"Your Python Code Name Goes Here.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec(open("filename.py").read())`

Comment: Including an explanation why this should be used is always helpful.

Comment: It is an easy one-liner that does not need the import of a library.